# Regex Minimum character/digit

Tags: regex, validation, passwords

I can't figure out the correct regular expression for the following password criteria:

Minimum of 2 or more uppercase, 2 or more lowercase, 2 or more digits, 1 or more special characters.

```
(?!^[0-9]*[A-Z][0-9]*$)
(?!^[0-9]*[a-z][0-9]*$)
(?!^[a-zA-Z]*[0-9][a-zA-Z]*$)
```

I tried this but it doesn't match if the characters are not consecutive:

```
^([a-z]{2,})$
^([A-Z]{2,})$
^([0-9]{2,})$
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
([a-z].*[a-z])
([A-Z].*[A-Z])
([0-9].*[0-9])
```

Note that the `^` and `$` aren't needed in this case.

This wouldn't work too well if you needed three or more characters, as it would start to get pretty inefficient. But for just two or more, it should work all right.

Answer (score 1):

If whatever language you are using regex in allows for look aheads:

```
^(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9)(?=.*[SPECIAL CHARACTERS])
```

If you wanted to add a minimal, and/or max length, just append `.{min,max}$` to the regex. Infact, any other verifications can be appended because this method does not consume characters after making the inital match of two lowercase letters, two uppercase letters, two digits, and 1 special character

Answer (score 0):

I'm just gonna throw it out there that while it's technically possible to validate this with a single regex and no conditions, it's not particularly useful to do it that way, from a user experience perspective.  What would be better is for you to tell the user something more useful than "your password failed". Since you didn't specify what language you are using, I'm going to demonstrate a more useful approach, using php:

Here is an example script that will spit out more detailed error messages, based on your requirements.

```
<?php

if ($_POST['password']) {
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  preg_match_all('~([a-z])|([A-Z])|([0-9])|(\W)~',$password,$parts);

  $lowerAlpha = array_filter($parts[1]);
  $upperAlpha = array_filter($parts[2]);
  $numbers = array_filter($parts[3]);
  $special = array_filter($parts[4]);

  $errors = array();
  if (count($lowerAlpha)<2) $errors[] = 'at least 2 lowercase letters required';
  if (count($upperAlpha)<2) $errors[] = 'at least 2 uppercase letters required';
  if (count($numbers)<2) $errors[] = 'at least 2 numbers required';
  if (count($special)<1) $errors[] = 'at least one special character required';

  if (count($errors)==0) {
   // password is great, do something!
  } else {
    echo "password didn't make the cut for the following reasons:<br/>";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($errors);
    echo "</pre>";
  }
}
if (!isset($password)) $password = '';

?>

<form action='' method='post'>
  <input type='text' name='password' value='<?php echo $password; ?>'>
    <input type='submit' value='verify'>
</form>
```

Comment: I actually despise these sorts of systems. I'd rather know ALL requirements for each field when there's an error instead of only those I didn't pass. for example: `SReject_` would only output the error telling me I needed two digits. So what if I then tried `SReject01`? Wouldn't it make more sense to tell all requirements instead of having to guess and check?

Comment: @SReject well yes I agree with you.  I too want to know what the requirements are ahead of time. I do a lot of QA on clients' sites and that's one of my pet peeves, being told I didn't do it right but there's nothing telling me what I'm supposed to actually do.  So yes I agree, there should be a label or tooltip or something saying what the reqs are in the first place.  But the code I have shown IMO is also helpful in that it shows what exactly you missed.